# I could not display a different different maps

Tags: angular, openlayers-6

```
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

layers: any;
base_maps:any;

map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM({
        maxZoom: 23,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [15997148, 29099],
    zoom: 3.5,
  }),
});

Topo1() {
  this.Topo = new Map({
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1,
    }),
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZ({
          attributionsCollapsible: true,
          url: #####
          maxZoom: 23,
        }),
      }),
    ],
  });

  this.base_maps = new Layer({ 
    layers: [this.Topo],
    this.map.addLayer(this.base_maps); 
  })
}
```

HTML code:
`<input type="radio" (click)="Topo()"/>`
I have tried to display different maps depending on event click, but it's not working. inside the method the topo map is not working outside the method topo is working

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `this.Topo` as a map. To add a layer to an existing map it must be a layer

```
 this.Topo = new TileLayer({
   source: new XYZ({
     attributionsCollapsible: true,
    url: #####
     maxZoom: 23,
   }),
 });
 
 this.map.addLayer(this.Topo);
```